# JavaFX 8 Pagination place page numbers at top

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8

I am using a JavaFX 8 `Pagination` control.
The page navigation appears at the bottom, but I would like it to appear at the top, above the actual data that's displayed.

How can I show the page navigation (the row of numbers and the arrow buttons) at the top of the `Pagination`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess the easiest solution is to use several rotations.

These three CSS selectors do the trick:

```
.pagination { -fx-rotate:180; }
.pagination .pagination-control { -fx-rotate:180; }
.pagination .page { -fx-rotate:180; }
```

**Explanation:**

By checking the [CSS reference of](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#pagination) `Pagination`:

- The style class of the whole control is `pagination`.
- The substructure contains the displayed page with the style class of `page`
- And the page navigation area with the style class of `pagination-control`

> - page — StackPane
> - pagination-control — StackPane
>
>   - leftArrowButton — Button
>   - ....

So, what the CSS selectors do is to rotate the whole control, then rotate the sub-parts back.

*An example `Pagination` using these selectors:*

[image]

Comment: I really didn’t think there would be a way to do this without relying on undocumented internal structure.  Excellent solution.

Comment: This is really clever.  It's not what I ended up doing in the end - largely because I solved the problem before you posted this.  But it's a lot shorter than what I did, and more robust.  (I used "undocumented internal structure").